# Sentencia sql para cargar una tabla de una base de datos en un jtable

Tags: java, sql

Tengo tablas relacionadas en mi base de datos. Las tablas y sus campos son:

```
socios
    Id                    Integer clave primaria auto increment
    numero_socio          int
    nombre                varchar
    apellidos             varchar
    nif                   varchar
    fecha_nac             date
    telefono              int
    correo                varchar
    direccion             varchar
    fecha_alta            date
    fecha_baja            date

asamblea

    id                    clave primaria auto increment
    acta                  mediumtext
    tipo                  varchar
    fecha                 date
    convocante            varchar

junta_directiva

    id clave              primaria auto increment
    id_socio_presidente   int (relación con id de un socio)
    id_socio_secretario   int (relación con id de un socio)
    id_socio_vocal1       int (relación con id de un socio)
    id_socio_vocal2       int (relación con id de un socio)
    id_socio_vocal3       int (relación con id de un socio)
    id_asamblea           int (relación con id de una asamblea)
    periodo               varchar
```

Bien, pues quiero cargar en un `jtable` los datos de la tabla `junta_directiva` donde quiero mostrar nombre y apellidos de los socios (presidente, secretario y vocales) y la fecha de las asambleas.

Hice este código pero no funciona bien ya que me carga datos de una misma junta directiva en diferentes filas del jtable:

```
public void cargar(String valor) {
        try {

//Títulos de las columnas de la tabla
            String[] titulos = {"Id", "Presidente", "Secretario", "Vocal 1", "Vocal 2", "Vocal 3", "Asamblea", "Periodo",};
            String[] registros = new String[8];
            model = new DefaultTableModel(null, titulos);
//Variable donde almacenamos la consulta a la tabla junta directiva
            //  String cons = "SELECT junta_directiva.id,socios.nombre n1,socios.nombre n2,socios.nombre n3,socios.nombre n4,socios.nombre n5,periodo,fecha from junta_directiva,asamblea,socios WHERE socios.id = junta_directiva.id_socio_presidente AND socios.id = junta_directiva.id_socio_secretario AND socios.id=junta_directiva.id_socio_vocal1 AND socios.id=junta_directiva.id_socio_vocal2 AND socios.id=junta_directiva.id_socio_vocal3 AND asamblea.id = junta_directiva.id_asamblea ";
            String cons = "Select junta_directiva.id,socios.nombre, apellidos,fecha,periodo,id_socio_presidente from junta_directiva,socios,asamblea where socios.id = junta_directiva.id_socio_presidente and asamblea.id = junta_directiva.id_asamblea";
            String cons1 = "Select nombre, apellidos from socios, junta_directiva where junta_directiva.id_socio_secretario = socios.id";
            String cons2 = "Select socios.nombre, apellidos from socios, junta_directiva where junta_directiva.id_socio_vocal1 = socios.id";
            String cons3 = "Select socios.nombre, apellidos from socios, junta_directiva where junta_directiva.id_socio_vocal2 = socios.id";
            String cons4 = "Select socios.nombre, apellidos from socios, junta_directiva where junta_directiva.id_socio_vocal3 = socios.id";

            Statement st = cn.createStatement();
            Statement st1 = cn.createStatement();
            Statement st2 = cn.createStatement();
            Statement st3 = cn.createStatement();
            Statement st4 = cn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(cons);
            ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery(cons1);
            ResultSet rs2 = st2.executeQuery(cons2);
            ResultSet rs3 = st3.executeQuery(cons3);
            ResultSet rs4 = st4.executeQuery(cons4);

            //Introducimos los registros de la base de datos en la tabla
            while (rs.next() && rs1.next() && rs2.next() && rs3.next() && rs4.next()) {
                registros[0] = rs.getString("id");
                registros[1] = rs.getString("nombre") + " " + rs.getString("apellidos");
                registros[2] = rs1.getString("nombre") + " " + rs1.getString("apellidos");
                registros[3] = rs2.getString("nombre") + " " + rs2.getString("apellidos");
                registros[4] = rs3.getString("nombre") + " " + rs3.getString("apellidos");
                registros[5] = rs4.getString("nombre") + " " + rs4.getString("apellidos");
                registros[6] = rs.getString("fecha");
                registros[7] = rs.getString("periodo");


                model.addRow(registros);
            }
            jTable1.setModel(model);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(0);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(0);
            jTable1.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMaxWidth(0);
            jTable1.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setMinWidth(0);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setMaxWidth(0);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setMinWidth(0);
            jTable1.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setMaxWidth(0);
            jTable1.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setMinWidth(0);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setMaxWidth(0);
            jTable1.getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setMinWidth(0);
            jTable1.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setMaxWidth(0);
            jTable1.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(7).setMinWidth(0);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Agradecería una solución para que me cargue las juntas directivas correctamente en la tabla.
PD creo que el problema es que se debería hacer con una sola consulta

Answer (score 1):

Como indicaste, lo más fácil es traer todo en una sola consulta para que el manejador de base de datos relacione las tablas de manera correcta. Aquí te dejo la consulta que debe funcionar en cualquier manejador ya que no pusiste en que estás trabajando.

```
SELECT a.fecha     AS fechaAsamblea,
       p.nombre    AS NombrePresidente,
       p.apelidos  AS ApellidosPresidente,
       s.nombre    AS NombreSecretario,
       s.apelidos  AS ApellidosSecretario,
       v1.nombre   AS NombreVocal1,
       v1.apelidos AS ApellidosVocal1,
       v2.nombre   AS NombreVocal2,
       v2.apelidos AS ApellidosVocal2,
       v3.nombre   AS NombreVocal3,
       v3.apelidos AS ApellidosVocal3
FROM junta_directiva jd
JOIN socios   p  ON jd.id_socio_presidente = p.id
JOIN socios   s  ON jd.id_socio_secretario = s.id
JOIN socios   v1 ON jd.id_socio_vocal1 = v1.id
JOIN socios   v2 ON jd.id_socio_vocal2 = v2.id
JOIN socios   v3 ON jd.id_socio_vocal3 = v3.id
JOIN asamblea a  ON jd.id_asamblea = a.id;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funciona bien los socios. En fecha asamblea me salta un 6 (supongo que al ser el registro 6 en el array). El código es este:                 registros[6] = rs.getString("fechaAsamblea");   No sé si habría que hacer un getDate y una conversión y en ese caso ¿Cómo se haría?. Pd: en la consulta también quiero sacar el id y el periodo de la tabla junta_directiva. Gracias de antemano

Comment: Según tu publicación, la fecha de la asamblea es un tipo `date`. Es posible que necesites darle formato correcto al convertirla a `string`. Para agregar más columnas (no campos) solo necesitas agregarlos a la lista de columnas en la consulta con su prefijo de alias de tabla y el alias de la columna que quieras darle. Solo sigue el ejemplo del resto ya que la tabla está lista para ser consumida.

Comment: Vale ya funciona bien. Muchas gracias